# Logical AND operator on negative number in C

Tags: c++, logical-operators, operator-precedence

there!! Why's the output different in both codes whereas logic is same!!

Code 1:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int a, b, c, d;
  a = b = 1;
  c = a || --b;
  d = a-- && --b;
  cout << a << "\t" << b << "\t" << c << "\t" << d << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
~ ❯ g++ main.cpp && ./a.out 
0       0       1       0
```

Code 2:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() { cout << -1 && 1; }
```

Output:

```
~ ❯ g++ main.cpp && ./a.out 
-1~ ❯
```

Code 3:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() { cout << 1 && -1; }
```

Output:

```
~ ❯ g++ main.cpp && ./a.out 
1~ ❯
```

I guess it's doing bitwise operation. But I'm not sure, please help.

Moreover, I tried same in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf("%d\n", -1 && 1);
  printf("%d\n", 1 && -1);
}
```

Output:

~ ❯ cc -Wall main.c && ./a.out
1
1

It's very confusing. I think it's implementation-dependent as both C and C++ compiler behaved differently. Please spread some light on it.

Comment: Operator presidence, add some brackets. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: Disclaimer: **I don't know C++**. Try `cout << (1 && -1);` so that (possibly) the compiler doesn't interpret the expression as `(cout << 1) && -1;`

Comment: Suggestion: turn on all your compiler warnings. **Mind the warnings!!**

Comment: Thanks @pmg , it worked but why does it output 0 for d in Code 1.

Comment: Don't do `c = a || --b;` or `d = a-- && --b;` The side-effects on `b` may or may not be executed.

Comment: The precedence for `<<` is sometimes a bit uncomfortable, and like many other things, it's for historical reasons; when it means bit-shifting, you *want* `a << b && c` to be `(a << b) && c`, so that's what C did, and C++ inherited. It would have been nice with a unique operator instead, but Stroustrup and C++ have always preferred repurposing an existing thing to adding one, even if it gets quirky at times.

Comment: In C (and, I believe, in C++) the result of [logical operator](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.13) (`&&` and `||`) is an `int` of value `0` or `1`.

Comment: @pmg In C++, it's a `bool` for all primitive type operands. With overloading, the value can be anything or nothing at all.

Comment: Thanks @molbdnilo; that was unexpected (teach me (again) to keep my mouth shut about C++)

Answer (score 1):

As people already disclosed, the issue is that `cout << 1`  is what is first executed during runtime, then `&& -1`, because that's how the operation order works.
However, if you change your command to `cout << (1 && -1);`, the order changes, so that the parenthesis is first executed, then the output of the operation is passed onto `cout`.
Lastly, although not importart to the question, putting an `endl` to the end of your `cout`s is common practice, something like this: `cout << (1 && -1) << endl;`

Comment: `&&` is not a bitwise operation, `&` is.